# View Mode not showing up under Manage Display

Tags: 8, entities

I created a view mode let's call as my_node_view for content type under display type settings, I was expecting it to show along with default and teaser tabs as default|teaser|my_node_view in manage display section, but it did not show up. I have ensured my_node_view is checked under custom display settings for Use `custom display settings for the following modes`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to provide the code here. That way only we can help.

Comment: Did you try a cache clear? I remember seeing an issue that a manual cache clear is necessary for this. @PHP Weblineindia: There is no code necessary for any of this in D8.

Comment: @Berdir clear cache did the job, can you please add it as answer, I am adding it in drupal issue queue as configurations should not require a manual cache clear.

Comment: Added issue on D.O. https://www.drupal.org/node/2422293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing out my comment as an answer.

This apparently needs a manual cache clear right now to work.